# Text Being Output Instead of HTML

Tags: html

I've got a really cool sorting carousel working on a JS Fiddle, but when I switched from outputting words to outputting images, the text for the images

```
<img src="http://i242.photobucket.com/albums/ff231/bour3/things%20I%20made%20then%20ate/hamburger.jpg" alt="" title=""/>
```

is showing up instead of the actual images.

I've tried adding the HTML tags during the `addNextImage` function instead of in the `images` array and I've tried replacing the symbols with encodings, but so far I can't get the images to show up.

```
carousel.addNextImage = function () {
    var nextImage = images.shift();
    this.images = this.images || [];
    this.images.push(nextImage);
    this.slickAdd($('<div>', { text: nextImage }));
};
```

You can take a look at one of my tries on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MichelleGlauser/R7MCW/1/).

How can I get the HTML to show up as HTML and not as text?

Comment: Closed due to the nature of the error, then up-voted because you included the code to make it possible to answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't putting text in, you're putting in html so your function needs to read:

```
carousel.addNextImage = function () {
    var nextImage = images.shift();
    this.images = this.images || [];
    this.images.push(nextImage);
    this.slickAdd($('<div>', { html: nextImage }));
};
```

Comment: In the other versions, I took the "text" out altogether and since forgot about it. Thanks!

Comment: I hate it when I make silly errors like this! hehe /cc @MichelleGlauser